# Dynamic Akka streams sink

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I want to build a graph in Akka streams where the source is a Kafka topic (topic_a) and the sink is topic_b (always) and, depending on the message's data, also topic_c (the output message will be different than the output message that was sent to topic_b).

Is there any way to achieve this in Akka streams? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please show your code for at least consuming from your source and forwarding those events to the sink? And do you really need Akka? Kafka Steams can do this on its own with branching methods

Comment: I don't have any code yet, just checking the possibility. Kafka streams isn't good for my use case since we are using a topic per organization and therefore we can't scale it. @OneCricketeer

Comment: Scale what exactly? Akka Streams requires more resources than Kafka Streams would. Number of topics doesn't really matter since the client api is all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a graph like this one:

```
topicASource ~> broadcast               ~> topicBSink
                broadcast ~> filterFlow ~> topicCSink
```

It can be easily created using [graphs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html) or [simplified API](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html#combining-sources-and-sinks-with-simplified-api).

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to also change the message format so it'll be different from B to C?

Comment: You can attach any flow before the sinks and convert the message however you like. Standard operators like [map](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/map.html) are available. For example `Flow[String].map(_.toUpperCase)` converts a string to upper case. More examples are available in graphs documents that I've linked in the answer.